# How to create a map view inside documentset

Tags: document-library, document-set, localization, picture, geolocation

In SharePoint 2013, I've a library with content type **Document Set**.
Inside the document set I've a content type "Picture" with column geolocation.

Are there a way to have a view map inside my document set?

Comment: Can you give a sample to do this?